# blurring out or display half of the content of the pdf file

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf

Is there a way to `blur out the contents in pdf programmatically`? If not blur, just `display the 3 pages out of 10` when users view the pdf. I am making a program where users can view the page, but only the tip of it... like the table of contents, if they are interested on it they can request to the admin for file download.

What I've search was `redacted pdf`, which I manually need to save the file. The pdf file have like 10 pages up.

If it's possible that this can be done through php/js. I don't have any code yet since I am trying to search for some ideas but nothing shows up.

Similar Function: It's like something like the pay per view of some websites, when you are reading there's like a notice that you need to pay to read the whole pdf.

Comment: You can check out the Document viewer from the LEADTOOLS JS toolkit which also provides [redaction in the document library](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/javascript/to/document-view-and-convert-redaction.html). Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor of this SDK